# Flex pseudo elements not animating on hover

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions

This is just a simplified example, I have list items that each have flex item after pseudo element. I'm using these to animate an underline effect on hover. When the display is changed it works but when I use flex there is no effect. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/79ftcx48/2/

```css
html div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

html div>* {
  background-color: slategrey;
  margin: 0 5px 0;
  color: floralwhite;
  padding: 5px;
}

html div ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: auto;
  order: -1;
}

html div ul li::after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  height: 1px;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 300s ease;
  background-color: peru;
  order: -1;
}

html div ul li:hover::after {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <aside>
    This is the aside
  </aside>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum text is pretty freaking dumb.
  </p>

</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this not supported by browsers?

Comment: Can you please give an example without the `flex` where the behaviour is as expected?

Comment: are you sure you want to wait 300s for the transition? if so you will notice that it's working fine

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  That was it, thank you!!! Please close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your code because most of it doesn't have any relation to the problem, which is simply a very long transition duration. 300s. That's 5 minutes! Testing with 1s below. Your code works fine.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

div>* {
  background-color: slategrey;
  margin: 0 5px 0;
  color: floralwhite;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: auto;
  order: -1;
}

div ul li::after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background-color: peru;
}

ul li:hover::after {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <aside>
    This is the aside
  </aside>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum text is pretty freaking dumb.
  </p>
</div>
```